# Where to insert encoded stream in YouTube Live Streaming API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am working on a project which will perform live streaming on YouTube.

So far I have created a live event and stream and bind them together.

After creating stream I got ingestion address and unique stream name.

But now my question is where to pass encoded streams so that it could be live.

I have encoded streams.

For testing purpose I want to pass those steam with the help of ingestion address, but I am struggling into it.

I am using the Java sample to create broadcast.

Answer (score 2):

You pass the encoded streams to the [`ingestionAddress`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#cdn.ingestionInfo.ingestionAddress) returned from your `liveStream` object.  The valid ingestions formats are either RTMP or DASH video with the `streamName` as the key.

If you're using RTMP, your ingestion address looks something like `rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the ingestion Address. But i am not able to figure out how to insert it. Is there any code sample available for the same  ?

Comment: @Rajeevkumar you are asking how to create an RTMP encoder, which is far too broad of a question for Stack Overflow.